# Correct syntax for finding all rows with same ID when a certain cell contains a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I've got to tables merged in SQL. Now i want the output to just show me all rows with the same ID's when a cell contains a certain text.
This probably is peanuts, but I just can't seem to find the correct syntax using SQL Express 2013.

Example :

| ID | ARTICLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Coke |
| 1 | Coke Light |
| 2 | Coke |
| 2 | Coke Light |
| 2 | Fanta |

The result should only show all the ID rows where one of them contains a Fanta. So in this case :

| ID | ARTICLE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Coke |
| 2 | Coke Light |
| 2 | Fanta |

The example is a simplified version of the original table. And the query needs to be kept as simple as possible, due to limitations of the external program that needs to run the query.

Comment: You should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: The result should only show all the ID rows where one of them contains a Fanta. So in this case :

ID ARTICLE
2 Coke
2 Coke Light
2 Fanta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following join query:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.ARTICLE
FROM table_name T
JOIN
  (SELECT ID FROM table_name WHERE ARTICLE ='Fanta') D
ON T.ID=D.ID
```

If your sample input date is populated from another query, you may use CTE as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(your query)
SELECT T.ID, T.ARTICLE
FROM CTE T
JOIN
 (SELECT ID FROM CTE WHERE ARTICLE ='Fanta') D
ON T.ID=D.ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/baB5gqI5).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a windowed conditional count

```sql
SELECT
  t.ID,
  t.Article
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      c = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Article = 'Fanta' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE c > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your threshold is for "simple" or why the external program is sensitive about that, but this is about the best compromise between simplicity and efficiency:

```
SELECT ID, Article
  FROM dbo.YourTableName AS t
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTableName AS i
      WHERE i.ID = t.ID
      AND i.Article = 'Fanta'
  );
```

Working example in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GpxHT-aK).

Answer (score 0):

Great work!

Working around with the answers gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It is more of a thank you answer. Please delete it and accept the answer that helped the most.  Post thank you comments (when you have sufficient reputation) on the other answers. You may also upvote answers at 15 reputation.